# Quartz.net db Jobs only work if added as singleton

Tags: quartz.net

I have a program where I add my jobs into a db and schedule them as needed. I used to add my jobs in program.cs as singletons, which works fine but only allows me to add a single job per scheduler and I can't check if it's already there. So I moved all that into one scheduler, where I now check if the job's already in my db and if it isn't then I add it.

It adds the jobs fine but they don't work at all, whenever I try to call one I get a nullreference exception from JobRunShell.Run(). I can't for the life of me figure out why, the job looks exactly the same in the db and I can't find anything wrong with my code. Am I not supposed to add jobs like that?

Program.cs with job added as singleton

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IJobFactory, JobFactory>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerFactory, StdSchedulerFactory>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MailHRNewEmployee>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(new JobMetadata(Guid.NewGuid(), typeof(MailHRNewEmployee), "HR First Contact", "job blueprint"));
builder.Services.AddHostedService<MyScheduler>();
```

MyScheduler.cs

```
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //Creating Scheduler
            Scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
            Scheduler.JobFactory = jobFactory;

            //Start Scheduler
            await Scheduler.Start(cancellationToken);

            //Create Jobs
            var istrue = await Scheduler.CheckExists(new JobKey("HR First Contact", "DEFAULT"));
            if (!(bool)istrue)
            {
                jobMetaData = new JobMetadata(Guid.NewGuid(), typeof(MailHRNewEmployee), "HR First Contact", "job blueprint");
                IJobDetail jobDetail = CreateJob(jobMetaData);
                await Scheduler.AddJob(jobDetail, true);
            }

...(checking all the other jobs)

       private IJobDetail CreateJob(JobMetadata jobMetadata)
        {
            return JobBuilder.Create(jobMetaData.JobType).WithIdentity(jobMetaData.JobName.ToString()).StoreDurably(true).WithDescription(jobMetaData.JobDescription).Build();
        }
```

Exception Stack Trace for NullReferenceException

```
[10:43:31 ERR] Job DEFAULT.HR First Contact threw an unhandled Exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Quartz.Core.JobRunShell.Run(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[10:43:32 ERR] Job DEFAULT.HR First Contact threw an exception.
Quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception.
 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Quartz.Core.JobRunShell.Run(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- [See nested exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Quartz.Core.JobRunShell.Run(CancellationToken cancellationToken)]
```

**Edit:**

I tried using the MS DI Integration library with Quartz Hosted services but couldn't get it to work with persistent Job storage & MySql.

```
    builder.Services.Configure<QuartzOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Quartz"));
builder.Services.Configure<QuartzOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Scheduling.IgnoreDuplicates = true;
    options.Scheduling.OverWriteExistingData = true;
});

builder.Services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
    q.SchedulerId = "Job Creator";
    q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();


    var jobKey = new JobKey("HR First Contact", "DEFAULT");
    q.AddJob<MailHRNewEmployee>(jobKey, j => j
        .StoreDurably()
        .WithDescription("job blueprint"));

    q.UsePersistentStore(s =>
    {
        s.PerformSchemaValidation = true;
        s.UseProperties = true;
        s.RetryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        //Neither .UseMySql nor UseMySqlConnector work
        //MySqlConnector should be the one I want though
        s.UseMySqlConnector(MySql =>
        {
            //I am loading the configuration above but don't know how to use the connection string here?
            //I thought it would maybe be Configuration.GetConnectionString("xyz");
            MySql.ConnectionString = "MyConnectionString";
            MySql.TablePrefix = "QRTZ_";
        });
        s.UseJsonSerializer();
    });
});
builder.Services.AddTransient<MailHRNewEmployee>();

builder.Services.AddQuartzHostedService(options =>
{
    options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jobs should be registered as transient, Quartz expects to get a new instance from job factory. Have you considered using the [MS DI integration library](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/microsoft-di-integration.html) and [hosted services integration library](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/hosted-services-integration.html)?

Comment: Does every job need a new job factory instance? I'm passing the one I'm creating in program.cs to myscheduler.cs; that's not enough?   I tried using MS DI with Quartz hosted services, following your tutorial, but it doesn't work(see edit above)

Comment: Job factory is global to scheduler instance, so there's one instance per scheduler instance. It's impossible say what's wrong with your configuration without error logs. Make at least sure you have correct database driver installed as NuGet dependency.